# XmlNodeList.Cast<XmlNode>() returns null

Tags: c#, xml, list, xmlnodelist

Here is something I can not get :

```
IEnumerable<XmlNode> list = xml.SelectNodes(xpath).Cast<XmlNode>();
```

returns `null` *in vs debug*

Whereas

```
IEnumerable<XmlNode> list = new List<XmlNode>(xml.SelectNodes(xpath).Cast<XmlNode>());
```

returns the nodes.

---

There seams to be a `yield return` somewhere in the code before...

```
IEnumerable<string> xpaths = ...;
xpaths = xpaths.GroupBy(r => r).Select(r => r.Key);

foreach(xpath in xpaths)
{
    IEnumerable<XmlNode> list = xml.SelectNodes(xpath).Cast<XmlNode>();
    //...
}
```

Comment: [`.Cast<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406) never returns null ... Or are you referring to the items?

Comment: please, [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) ...

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a full [mcve] of your problem.  You wrote *There seams to be a `yield return` somewhere in the code before...* if so, please include that in the complete example.

Comment: Actually, the xpath comes from a list build by a linq expression. The code I show is in a `foreach` loop. I quite sure the `null` values I saw in debug are related to the linq expression that - I guess - uses a yield return...

Comment: If by *returns `null`* you mean *looks like `null` when displayed by the Visual Studio debugger*, then that's because, as explained in the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406(v=vs.110).aspx), **[`Enumerable.Cast<>()`] is implemented by using deferred execution.**.  As soon as you enumerate the results (e.g. by adding them to a list) you will be able to see the results in Visual Studio.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, it helped...